# Jquery Image slide panel on mouse over

Tags: jquery

I am creating a website for one school , for that i would like to make the slide show as like as the below website , http://wwwm.coventry.ac.uk/Pages/index.aspx , How can i get that image slide code ? Please help me to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jquery-ui accordion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/